# Setenv: Type expression list treated as compound expression in initializer

Tags: c++, setenv

Getting `Type expression list treated as compound expression in initializer`
On both these function calls -

```
    char itoa(new_total, new_total_ch, 10);
    int setenv("COUNT_TOTAL", new_total_ch, 1);
```

Here's the code snippet -

```
#include <iostream>
// create process team
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctime>
// initialize & process
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iosfwd>
// initialize & process
using std::ifstream;
using namespace std;

class Count3sProcessParallel {

public:
    //int process();
    int pr_count;
    int process();
    typedef int COUNT_TOTAL;


private:

    int worker;
    //declare process()
    long unit_of_work;
    long lower_bound;
    long upper_bound;
    int pr_i;
    char * ct;
    int ct_i;
    int new_total;
    char itoa();
    char * new_total_ch;
    int setenv();

};


int Count3sProcessParallel::process() {
    // determine upper lower bounds
    unit_of_work = in_length/workers_num;
    lower_bound = (worker -1) * unit_of_work;
    upper_bound = (worker * unit_of_work) -1;

    // iterate and count
    pr_count = 0;
    for (pr_i = lower_bound; pr_i < upper_bound; pr_i++)
      if (floor(in_buffer[pr_i] == 3))
        pr_count++;
        return pr_count;

    //update COUNT_TOTAL
    ct = getenv("COUNT_TOTAL");
    ct_i = atoi(ct);
    new_total = (pr_count + ct_i);
    char * new_total_ch[33];
    char itoa(new_total, new_total_ch, 10);
    int setenv("COUNT_TOTAL", new_total_ch, 1);

    delete[] in_buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `char itoa(new_total, new_total_ch, 10);`? At first I would say you got hit with the most vexing parse, but your question says that you are trying to call a function. Why would you throw in the `char` then?

Comment: @Pradhan - setenv takes "name" and "value" of type char. itoa is converting `net_total` to `new_total_ch` which is passed as the "value" by the setenv function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading types. Just use:

```
itoa(new_total, new_total_ch, 10);
setenv("COUNT_TOTAL", new_total_ch, 1);
```

Comment: Yes that did it. Seems straightforward now. Thank you.